# Is there a faster way to write a PySpark dataframe into a CSV file?

Tags: pyspark

I have to apply a filter, rename the columns and then save the PySpark dataframe. Currently I'm using the solution below. However, I need to reduce the processing time during the writing of the file.

```py
filtered_df = df.filter(df['vw_col1']==val) 

vw_cols = ['vw_col1', 'null', 'vw_col2']
csv_cols = ['csv_col1', 'csv_col2', 'csv_col3']
mapping = dict(zip(csv_cols, vw_cols))
select_cols = [df[mapping[c]].alias(c) if mapping[c] in olt_df.columns else lit(None).cast('string').alias(c) for c in csv_cols ]
final_df = filtered_df .select(select_cols)
final_df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").options(delimiter=";",header=True).csv(path_dir)
```

I've tried to implement a multiprocessing approach (example below), but did not work

```py
groups = [i.vw_col1 for i in df.select('vw_col1').distinct().collect()]
with Pool(processes=4) as pool: 
    pool.map(create_file_func, groups)
```

It's important to note that the original dataframe is not partitioned

Comment: With coalesce 1 you will force all the data into one partition, so it means that you will use only one core to write the data into disk. So if you remove the coalesce it should be faster.